# AngularJS remove ref documents first, then parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a remove function, but it's not well-coded. Sometimes it throws an error, because `game` is removed earlier than all milestones. How can I call `game.$remove()` only after all milestones are successfuly removed? Thank you very much!

```
$scope.remove = function(game) {
    if(game) { 
        var milestonesToDelete = MilestonesService.query({ gameId: game._id }, function(milestonesToDelete) {
            if(milestonesToDelete) {
                for(var i = 0; i < milestonesToDelete.length; i++) {
                    milestonesToDelete[i].$remove();
                }
            }
        });

        game.$remove();

        for (var j in $scope.games) {
            if ($scope.games [j] === game) {
                $scope.games.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $scope.game.$remove(function() {
            $location.path('admin/games');
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This is missing a lot of info. Tell us about the relation between `game` and `milestones`, or what kind of error message you're getting, etc.

Comment: If I'll comment line with `game.$remove()` and click remove button, it will delete all milestones without error (but not the game of course). Every milestone is assigned to game: `assignedToGame: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game'}`. I want to remove all milestones first, then remove game :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just need to remove the game after the milestones query completes. So just stick that code inside the async callback:

```
$scope.remove = function(game) {
    if(game) { 
        var milestonesToDelete = MilestonesService.query({ gameId: game._id }, function(milestonesToDelete) {
            if(milestonesToDelete) {
                for(var i = 0; i < milestonesToDelete.length; i++) {
                    milestonesToDelete[i].$remove();
                }
            }
            game.$remove();

            for (var j in $scope.games) {
                if ($scope.games [j] === game) {
                    $scope.games.splice(j, 1);
                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        $scope.game.$remove(function() {
            $location.path('admin/games');
        });
    }
};
```